# Excluding a specific package from a dependency in Gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle, gradlew

I have a dependency in one of my project

```
implementation (group: 'com.ibm.cloud', name: 'ibmcloudsql-jdbc', version: '2.5.34')
```

I want to specifically **exclude a package** from this jar, i.e

```
com.ibm.cloud.sdk.core.http
```

Is there a way? I already tried this but did not work.

```
implementation (group: 'com.ibm.cloud', name: 'ibmcloudsql-jdbc', version: '2.5.34'){
    exclude module: 'com.ibm.cloud.sdk.core.http'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use dependency management to remove part of a dependency - with dependency management it's either the complete dependency or no dependency (and this is not limited to gradle - other dependency managers / build systems like maven or ivy also don't have this feature).

The `exclude module` can only be used to prevent inclusion of transitive dependencies (i.e. you need dependency `com.xy:A` and `com.xy:A` declares that it also needs `com.xy:B` - with `exclude module` you can prevent the inclusion `com.xy:B`)

It might be possible to create your own version of that dependency by manually removing the package `com.ibm.cloud.sdk.core.http` from the jar itself and adding that modified jar file to your project.

Comment: Hi @Thomas Kläger
How can I create my own version of jar by manually removing the package from Jar itself? Any examples you can point me to?

Comment: @ChinmayDas the first question must be: why do you need it at all? The jdbc driver in that dependency needs the classes from `com.ibm.cloud.sdk.core.http` - it will not work without them.